# Add values to arraylist(in javascript) and retrieve in struts2 action

Tags: javascript, struts2

I want the selected values in the JSP to store in list (javascript) and retrieve them in struts2 action.

For example: If I have the following values, how can I store in list (javascript) and retrieve them in action

Dropdown  - Dropdown - textfield

ChannelName - Like - chan

ChannelType - OR - type2

I want the above values to be stored in javascript list and retrieve in struts2.

Please help me with this.

**Updated:**
JSP code

```
      <div class="row2">
<div class="left2">
        <select name="propType_1" id="propType_1">
           <option value="-1">Select property</option>
           <option value="3">keep-alive</option>
           <option value="2">transactionCapacity</option>
           <option value="1">capacity</option>
        </select>
</div>
<div class="left2">
        <select name="operType_3" id="operType_3">
            <option value="-1">Select operator</option>
            <option value="1">&amp;&amp;</option>
            <option value="2">Like</option>
            <option value="3">=</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="right2">
       <input type="text" name="prop1_value" value="" id="prop1_value"/>
    </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can u post your `jsp` code, i seem not to understand what u mean by `Dropdown - Dropdown - textfield`.

Comment: I have updated my question with the JSP code. If you see the code, there are 3 columns 1- dropdown,2-dropdown,3-textfield. In the same way I have 4 rows. How can I store these values in list and pass to strtus2 action.

Answer (score 0):

Use Struts tags when possible (`<s:select/>`, if you can provide your List from server-side), and avoid putting underscores in variables's name.

In Action:

```
private List<String>  propValue;
private List<Integer> propType;
private List<Integer> operType;

/* GETTERS AND SETTERS */
```

in JSP, if the source of the iteration is from server-side, or you have a known fixed amout of row :

```
<s:iterator begin="0" end="10" stat="ctr" >
    <select name="propType[<s:property value='%{#ctr.index}'/>]" >
       <option value="-1">Select property</option>
        <option value="1" >........</option>
    </select>
    <select name="operType[<s:property value='%{#ctr.index}'/>]" >
        <option value="-1">Select operator</option>
        <option value="1" >........</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="propValue[<s:property value='%{#ctr.index}'/>]" />
</s:iterator>
```

If the rows are variable and / or created with JavaScript, simply make sure that you are creating them with the same name and an index, in the format `variableName[index]`, handling your index as a javascript counter.

---

By the way the best option would be to create an object with your properties, and use a List of that object, instead of n Lists of n properties:

Row.java

```
public class Row {
    private String  propValue;
    private Integer propType;
    private Integer operType;

    /* GETTERS AND SETTERS */  
}
```

in Action:

```
private List<Row> rows;
/* GETTER AND SETTER */
```

in JSP:

```
<s:iterator value="rows" stat="ctr" >
    <select name="rows[<s:property value='%{#ctr.index}'/>].propType" >
       <option value="-1">Select property</option>
        <option value="1" >........</option>
    </select>
    <select name="rows[<s:property value='%{#ctr.index}'/>].operType" >
        <option value="-1">Select operator</option>
        <option value="1" >........</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="rows[<s:property value='%{#ctr.index}'/>].propValue" />
</s:iterator>
```